# Can we have one click recaptcha only - not the picture puzzle captcha after it

Tags: html, recaptcha, captcha

I integrated recaptcha in my forms
(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

However it is very confusing when the rest of the form has not be filled properly, then a picture-captcha opens. this is very troubling.

Can this be prevented? I would like just the recaptcha with 1 click-confirmation, even if the form has not been filled in completely.

Comment: No, the puzzle is to confirm you're really a human. It only shows if google cannot verify from the start you are a human. This is part of recaptcha.

Comment: Google could provide that option. But they wont. Because they want us to solve puzzles which help their machine learning algorithms. Behind every free google service there is business model. Even if the recaptcha algorithm identifies it is human it still force user to solve puzzles. Google wants as many puzzles as possible to be solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not.

Here is short explanation of google recaptcha settings:

When You create new key or edit existing, You can see in **Key Settings** section, the **Advanced settings**. When You show them, there is possibility to set **Security Preference**. But still it doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks for testing @Arun sankar. Also i did test by myself.

[image: captcha]

Default setting is in the middle.

Answer (score 5):

If you got here because you were looking for a way to temporarily disable the puzzle for automated testing: There are test keys that you can use for this purpose.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is NO.

Google does all the magic.

They have not provided any customization on security levels.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#config

The above article provide the available options for customization.

Answer (score 0):

YES. Now you can do it using [Invisible reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) and also [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3).

Comment: Actually this is not true... If you do some tests on website, and invisible captcha will be "auto filled" multiple times, then reCAPTCHA will show you additional window to be filled by yourself. Just like in reCAPTCHA V2. And You can't prevent it either.